# How to add hierarchical taxonomy with parent child relation to URL?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a custom taxonomy named 'location'. Where country and city of country is listed as parent child relation.

Suppose `India` is location taxonomy while `Delhi` and `Mumbai` are also location taxonomy under `India`

Post have selected relevant city along with country taxonomy already.

So for an example: Post 1 has `Delhi` & `India` taxonomy selected, while Post 2 has `Mimbai` & `India` taxonomy selected while publishing.

Now what I am trying to do is: to have following URLs.

1. domain.com/India/
2. domain.com/India/Delhi/
3. domain.com/India/Mumbai/

Where first URL should display all the post from `India`, `Delhi` & `Mumbai`. While second URL should display post only from `Delhi` and same for `Mumbai`

Comment: Well this how hierarchical taxonomy URLs already work, you just need to have some sort of indication of what taxonomy it is, eg. `/location/india/delhi/`. Otherwise WordPress doesn't know whether to look for a page or a taxonomy term. Is this what you're problem is?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However I dont want to mentions `/location` (taxonomy name) to url only `/india/delhi/` should be there. Also I have multiple countries each with their major cities.